# Sudden crash with black screen showing /dev/sda1:

Tags: crash

Sometimes, for no apparent reason, my screen suddenly goes 'black', showing only one line of text:

```
/dev/sda1: clean 1068388/64102400 files, 29744985/256399616 blocks
```

as if the system would be restarting. But nothing happens after that and I have to press the reset button.

This has happened three times now. Once right after a fresh start in the morning and never with any big task running (just opening a browser - not reproducible). It never happened under extreme load (training neural nets), so I am pretty sure this is not a heat issue, as in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99450/302973).

I found the following suspicious lines in the `/var/log/kern.log` file

```
... [    0.024000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed
...
... [    0.796335] dpc 0000:00:01.1:pcie010: DPC error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 6, DL_ActiveErr+
```

where the last line appears three times in a row, but I don't know what that means.

I am running:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- Kernel: 4.15.0-39-generic (x86_64)
- Desktop: GNOME Shell 3.28.3
- Display Driver: NVIDIA 396.45
- Compiler: Clang 3.3 + LLVM 3.3 + CUDA 9.2
- File-System: ext4

On a pretty new desktop machine with specs:

- Processor: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1900X 8-Core @ 3.80GHz (16 Cores)
- Motherboard: ASRock X399 Professional Gaming
- Memory: 64512MB
- Disk: 1050GB Crucial_CT1050MX + 4001GB Elements SE 25FF
- Graphics: 2x SLI NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti 11264MB

What could be the cause of this problem?

### smartctl

In Response to comments, the output from

```
sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda
```

is

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Crucial_CT1050MX300SSD1
Serial Number:    173818DBA7DB
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00a075 118dba7db
Firmware Version: M0CR060
User C    apacity:    1.050.214.588.416 bytes [1,05 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Nov 17 14:39:52 2018 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 2783) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  13) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       454
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       333
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   074   059   000    Old_age   Always       -       26 (Min/Max 16/41)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0030   100   100   001    Old_age   Offline      -       0
206 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x000e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
246 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       945594898
247 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       29549867
248 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8744251
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0033   000   000   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       4424
210 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

### Update (logout instead of black screen)

Just now, instead of a black screen I just got logged out of my account for no apparent reason. It seems like those issues are related. Around the time of this event, Vim highlights these lines in the `kern.log`:

```
Nov 19 09:44:52 Gauss kernel: [    0.793729] dpc 0000:00:01.1:pcie010: DPC error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 6, DL_ActiveErr+
Nov 19 09:44:52 Gauss kernel: [    0.793735] dpc 0000:00:03.1:pcie010: DPC error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 6, DL_ActiveErr+
Nov 19 09:44:52 Gauss kernel: [    0.793744] dpc 0000:40:03.1:pcie010: DPC error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 6, DL_ActiveErr+
...
Nov 19 09:44:52 Gauss kernel: [    0.890282] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
...
Nov 19 09:44:52 Gauss kernel: [    1.026963] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
...
Nov 19 09:44:52 Gauss kernel: [    2.927217] scsi 10:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
Nov 19 09:44:52 Gauss kernel: [    2.927219] scsi 10:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
...
Nov 19 09:44:52 Gauss kernel: [    5.227132] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
...
Nov 19 09:44:52 Gauss kernel: [    5.602354] thermal thermal_zone0: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
```

Comment: First thing to do is install `smartmontools` and check the SMART data of your drives.

Comment: leaving a comment as I'm interested in the output of `smartctl --all /dev/sda` too.

Comment: @Fabby: I added this information.

Comment: Disk OK and rather new.  When did this problem crop up?  After an upgrade?

Comment: @Fabby: No, I just did my usual coding. The last things I changed in the system where `sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module` and `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386`, but I don't think that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Out of ideas with the information posted.  Can you post the full kernel.log somewhere else? (https://paste.ubuntu.com will do)

Comment: @Fabby: Here it is: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kHcwhZpdt4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85885/discussion-between-fabby-and-jem-mosig).

Answer (score 2):

That looks like your X11 or Wayland GUI server is crashing and dropping you back to a text-mode console. The one line of text is probably from a filesystem check that happened when booting the system, before switching into GUI mode. As Ubuntu 18.04 starts the GUI on the first virtual console, that virtual console will be non-responsive if the GUI server crashes and is not restarted.

(Other Linux distributions traditionally used the 7th virtual console for the GUI, causing the system to automatically revert to the default 1st virtual console with a functional login prompt on it on a X11 server crash. Ubuntu apparently moved the GUI server to the 1st virtual console to make a more seamless transition between the boot splash and the GUI login, but if the GUI server crashes, you'll now need to be aware of the virtual consoles to gain access to a text-mode login prompt.)

The lines in your `/var/log/kern.log` are all logged within a few seconds of Linux kernel start-up (according to the seconds-since-startup value in square brackets at the start of each line), so they're probably not directly related.

Try pressing <kbd>Control+Alt+F2</kbd>. If the kernel is still alive, you should now see a text-mode login prompt on the black screen. You could then log in and try `sudo systemctl restart gdm` to restart the GUI, or gather up logs and other troubleshooting information in text mode. Note that restarting `gdm` might automatically return you to the GUI, but the login session on the second virtual console will still remain logged in: you can probably toggle between them using <kbd>Control-Alt-F1</kbd> and <kbd>Control-Alt-F2</kbd>.

As the kernel log shows nothing, it might be that the kernel is just fine and just the desktop is crashing. In that case, other log files might be more helpful:

- `/var/log/gdm.log`
- `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` if it exists (hmm, what is the equivalent for Wayland?)

Disclaimer: I've not tried Ubuntu 18.04 myself; this answer is just based on what I've read about it.

Comment: There is no `gdm.log`, but `grep -E "EE|WW" Xorg.0.log` gives a couple of lines, including a "Failed to open DRM device". May this be related to my GPUs? Here is the pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zJ9Gqhfq9B/

Comment: Note that `Xorg.0.log` will get replaced each time the X11 server starts, so if you've already restarted the GUI or rebooted the system after the crash, look at the end of `Xorg.0.log.old` instead.

Comment: Ok, here is the full `Xorg.0.log.old` file: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/925mb7xMtz/ Thanks for your help! It says `xf86CloseConsole: KDSETMODE failed`, as well as `VT_GETMODE` and `VT_ACTIVATE`. And beforehand it mentioned my GPU.

Comment: Hmm, that looks like a successful X11 server shutdown with no significant errors. If that log is from a crash, then the reason is probably that the display manager process is crashing and causing the X11 session to end as a side effect. Is there any logfile matching `/var/log/*dm.log` on your system? Or if Ubuntu 18.04 has standardized on `journald`-based logging, make sure `/var/log/journal` directory exists and then you should be able to use `sudo journalctl -xb -1` to view the logs of the previous boot all the way to the shutdown.

Comment: I should have written down the exact times when it happened. Today I only got the unexpected logout. There is no `*dm.log`, but the `jounal`-thing worked. I pasted the logs around the critical point in time here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/37XmRYRpVK/

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit of a long shot, but I've had the exact same symptoms you described today on my machine (the crashes and then later the logout instead of black screen).

I'm also on Ubuntu 18.04 and using an Nvidia GPU.

With everyone mentioning that they assume this might be an issue with the Nvidida drivers I decided to give the answer in this thread a shot, even though it only partially applied to our issue:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w

1. Delete your nvidia drivers with

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
   ```
2. Reboot
3. Install the Nvidida drivers again

So far I've had no black screens or sudden logouts anymore

Comment: Ok, I'll try this!

Comment: Give us an update if it resolved the issue for you :).

Comment: Quick note: Since I am using `zsh` I had to put `nvidia*` into quotes, see https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/6748 .

Answer (score 0):

Another solution here. I already had the same problem and I could not find any of the suggested solutions to be useful for my case. 
I used VMware workstation and faced the same problem when Ubuntu starts booting. 
The main reason for the crash in my case was not due to the graphic card driver or things like this. 
There was not enough free space left in the installed Ubuntu. Therefore, I followed the following steps to solve the problem.

1) change the .vmx configuration file by adding the following line to it:

bios.bootDelay = "50000"

*This leads to longer boot delay, therefore, you can use Shift+Enter to enter the Grub Menu.

*If you have a problem in opening the .vmx file in windows, first change the extension of the file to .txt then add the aforementioned line to it and save the file and then change the extension back to .vmx

2) Run VMware and run Ubuntu

3) After clicking on the screen, press and hold Shift key down and then press Enter to enter the grub menu.

4) choose Advanced Options for Ubuntu.

5) choose root and then press Enter.

6) now you have the root access to delete any file to make free space in the Ubuntu.

Note that some users suggested using Alt+Shift+F2 or F3 to have access to the terminal. This did not work for me since I did not have a password for the root user. However, using the following steps helped me to resolve the problem.

Good Luck,
Hamed

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to ***gdm3*** not running. So I restarted it using these commands:

```
sudo service gdm3 status (to ckeck status)
sudo service gdm3 start
```

It doesn't matter if you are using lightgdm, gdm or gdm. To find out which one you are using try `sudo service --status-all | grep gdm`

Answer (score 0):

Here it is another solution that I have not seen elsewhere, I thought it can be helpful to share it.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, amd64 distro, and I had the same hanging at boot after displaying the "/dev/sda1: clean ..." error. In my case, the secondary cause of the problem was that the ***disk was full***.

So, if you have this symptom, do a quick `df` or `df -h` to see how much space you have left on the partition(s). Using the `du` or `du -h` commands, you can hone in on directories that contain large amount of data. The solution could be as simple as deleting unnecessary files.

In my case, however, turned out that the /var/log directory was about 100GB (?!) that was caused by some problem in the system resulting in writing to the /var/log/syslog file constantly and eventually filling up the drive. So, that was the primary cause of the problem. At this point I am not sure what resource is the culprit, but checking the /var/log/syslog file might provide some pointers in your case. If this is also the case for you, I recommend researching how to properly remove the /var/log/syslog file, then try to resolve the primary cause of the problem.

Since my system does not have any important things on it, hence I was not interested in keeping log files, I installed the logrotate package and set up a daily rotation and configuring the system to delete the rotated file. I also found a large journal file, so I set up a cronjob as root to delete journal files older than 1 day. This you can do by `crontab -e` as root and add this line to the end of file:

0 * * * * journalctl --vacum-time=1d

I also did an `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` cycle for good measure.

I recommend some further reading:



https://ma.ttias.be/clear-systemd-journal/

https://github.com/andyholmes/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/issues/588
https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do
https://kifarunix.com/how-to-configure-log-rotation-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

Have fun debugging and best of luck,

8bitrocks

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem on my computer which is related to this `/dev/sd*: clean` issue. I did not want to open up a new question since there are so many already and also because my issue seems to be fixed now. So I decided to write an answer to a related topic (where I can actually write an answer and do not need 10 reputation points or something like that).

Before I start, some specs:

- Ubuntu 18.04.4
- I'm dual-booting with Windows
- My PC has a AMD Radeon RX 5500 XT graphics card

For more specs I'm not thinking of right now---just let me know.

My first encounter of this problem looked like this: I was choosing Ubuntu in the dual-boot menu. This menu has a purple background. As I clicked Enter the menu disappeared (like it should) but the purple background stayed for at least 15 minutes. I decided to reboot. After some googling I managed to enter the recovery-mode where I edited in `/etc/default/grub` the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

I rebooted only to see the screen flashing the following message

```
/dev/sdb1: Superblock last mount time is in the future.
    (by less than a day, probably due to the hardware clock being incorrectly set)
/dev/sdb1: Superblock last write time is in the future.
    (by less than a day, probably due to the hardware clock being incorrectly set)
/dev/sdb1: clean, 30163/6594560 files, 5137309/26366943 blocks
```

every ~10 seconds for about ~0.5 seconds. Here I already 'knew' this issue is related to installed graphic drivers. I rebooted in recovery mode again to uninstall the drivers for the AMD graphics card

```
$ amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

After this, Ubuntu started normally, except for the fact that only 1 monitor was recognized with a resolution of 1024x768 which I could not change (I have 2 Monitors with 1920x1080). After some further googling I changed the file `etc/fstab` from

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=b440d779-f2d8-4e85-a425-86c264cf1086 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=4E80-9146  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=3b2456a3-8d84-41f8-81b1-094c3014126f /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=5d727b45-f3f0-40ad-8f6b-41528f8fb611 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

to

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=b440d779-f2d8-4e85-a425-86c264cf1086 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       0
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=4E80-9146  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=3b2456a3-8d84-41f8-81b1-094c3014126f /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=5d727b45-f3f0-40ad-8f6b-41528f8fb611 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

(I changed the last number `1` to a `0` in the first non-comment line).
I re-installed the AMD gpu driver, rebooted and the problem was gone. I'm writing this on my 2 monitors with 1920x1080 resolution.
I also removed the `nomodeset` in `/etc/default/grub`.

So if anyone has the same issue, maybe this person will find my answer and maybe my approach will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

8bitrock's solution worked for me after so many trial. Just do

sudo service gdm3 status (To see if gmd3 is active or not).

Then do sudo service gdm3 start  (This will help start it).

Comment: welcome to U&L, your solution is identical to smit  patel's. can you describe difference ?